# Why aren't text line endings uniform in GIT Despite * text=auto

Tags: java, sql, git

I'm working on a clone of an existing GIT repo and the .gitattributes specify `* text=auto !eol`.

From my reading of the documentation, text=auto specifies that all "text" files should be normalized in the repo.

> Git recognizes files encoded in ASCII or one of its supersets (e.g.
>   UTF-8, ISO-8859-1, …​) as text files

And "normalized" means LF only as a line ending.

So, I don't know how to check the line endings in the obfuscated repo, but in the workspace I'm getting a mix of text (.java / .sql files). Some with LF and others with CRLF line endings.

Since .gitattributes' `!eol` means no specification for workspace line endings, I assumed they'd be as they are in the repo.

So, why the mix? Ideally I'd like to have all text file lines end with LF in both repo and workspace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Since .gitattributes' `!eol` in means no specification for workspace line endings, I assumed they'd be as they are in the repo.

Yes, but just because `text=auto` is *currently set* does not mean that the files *are* checked in with LF. And just because a file is checked in with LF does not mean that the working copy has to be LF. It just means that anything new that you check in will be converted from CRLF to LF during checkin... but not the working copy!

So in short, you're getting a mix of CRLF and LF because the repo has a mix of CRLF and LF. All `text=auto` does is make it so *new* stuff checked in will be LF in the repo.

### Example

Here is an example to illustrate.

Let's start by creating a new repository and adding a text file with CRLF line endings:

```
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /.../test/.git/
$ cat > file.txt
line 1
line 2
$ unix2dos file.txt
unix2dos: converting file file.txt to DOS format...
$ git add file.txt
$ git commit -m 'added file'
[master (root-commit) f21d72f] added file
 1 file changed, 2 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 file.txt
```

At this point, the file in the repository *and* the file in the working copy both have CRLF.

We will now set `text=auto eol`. This does not change the file or mark it as dirty. It's still CRLF.

```
$ cat > .gitattributes
* text=auto !eol
$ git add .
$ git commit -m 'add .gitattributes'
[master 1844576] add .gitattributes
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 .gitattributes
$ file file.txt  
file.txt: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

We can remove the file and check it out, but because the file in the repository has CRLF, we still get CRLF on checkout.

```
$ rm file.txt
$ git checkout -- file.txt
$ file file.txt
file.txt: ASCII text, with CRLF, LF line terminators
```

Now let's add a new file with CRLF. This will get normalized in the repository, but the working copy will be unaffected.

```
$ cat > file2.txt
line 3
line 4
$ unix2dos file2.txt
unix2dos: converting file file2.txt to DOS format...
$ git add file2.txt
warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in file2.txt.
The file will have its original line endings
in your working directory
$ git commit -m 'added file 2'
[master cc2c5c3] added file 2
 1 file changed, 2 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 file2.txt
$ file file.txt file2.txt
file.txt:  ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
file2.txt: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
```

Even though this file is LF in the repository and CRLF in the working copy, it is not dirty and checking it out again will not change it.

```
$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean
$ git checkout -- file.txt file2.txt
$ file file.txt file2.txt
file.txt:  ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
file2.txt: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
```

We can get the LF version by *deleting it* and then checking it out again:

```
$ rm file2.txt
$ git checkout -- file2.txt
$ file file2.txt
file2.txt: ASCII text
```

Note that it has LF now.

### Setting eol=lf doesn't fix your repository

The `eol` setting only really works if your repository contains correctly normalized files to begin with. Changing it will not fix our `file.txt`.

```
$ cat >.gitattributes
*.txt text eol=lf
$ git commit -m 'set eol=lf'
[master c9e346b] set eol=lf
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
$ rm file.txt
$ git checkout -- file.txt
$ file file.txt
file.txt: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
```

### How to fix

The straightforward way to fix things, and get LF everywhere, is to actually run `dos2unix` on your files. Once you do this, and commit the normalized files, you will have LF everywhere on checkout.